# Checkbox ajax request on check/uncheck

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a checkbox on razor view engine as:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Attempt, new { id = "Attempt" })
```

I wanted to make ajax request on each check/uncheck on the checkbox. So, i used the javascript,

```
$(document).ready(function () {

// Some other functions here

        $('#Attempt input:checkbox').change(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("Select", "Test")',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { attempt: true }

            });

        })


    });
```

But it is not working at all. No request is being sent at all. What am i missing?
Also, how to map  data `attempt` true or false according to check/uncheck ?

Comment: `data: { attempt: true }` delete `,`

Comment: um ! actually there was success function just below i deleted success function and `,` was what remained there. That was not the error though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know why it didn't work but i modified slightly to make it work.

```
$('#Attempt').change(function () {
            if ($('#Attempt').is(':checked')) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("Select","Test")',
                    data: { isLocked: true },

                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: "json"
                });
            }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You selector says find an element that has an id Attempt and than find the checkboxes inside. I believe you selector should just be the id unless I do not understand the the plating language you are using.